# A limit calculation problem.

Tags: calculus, limits

I see in a book the following :

$$\lim_{\rho \rightarrow0}\frac{e^{\frac{f(i)}{\rho}}}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}e^{\frac{f(i)}{\rho}}}$$ is 1 for $i=\arg \max_{i}f(i)$ and $0$ otherwise. I don't see it immediately.

Comment: Divide everything by the numerator and maybe it'll be clearer. Basically this is a probability distribution tending to an 'atomic' distribution. (:

Answer (score 0):

Consider instead this, for some $m$
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac {\sum e^{f_i \cdot x}} {e^{f_m \cdot x}} = \sum \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac {e^{f_i \cdot x}} {e^{f_m \cdot x}} = \sum \lim_{x \to \infty} e^{(f_i-f_m) \cdot x}$$
Consider what happens when all $f_i-f_m$ are negative or $0$ and what happens if some of them are positive.